# HTML BUG challenge: big cursor for contenteditable div if using placeholder

Tags: html, css

Test the code below, you will find a big cursor in the contenteditable div. If removing the rule `:empty:before` the cursor problem seems to be fixed but the placeholder also disappeared. So I wondered how to make the cursor to the normal size but keep the placeholder at the same time?

```
 <html>
    <div id="comment_box" contenteditable="true" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Click me to see Omg what a big cursor"></div>

<style>

#comment_box{
    text-align: center;
  background-color: white;

  /*position:relative;*/
  border: 1px solid orange;
  /*height:60px;*/
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  color:black;
  border-radius:5px;
  /*font-size:18px;*/
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: bottom;

  /*border-color:yellow;*/
}
#comment_box:focus{
  outline-style:solid;
  outline-color:orange;
  outline-width:0px;
}


[contenteditable=true]:empty:before{
  content: attr(placeholder);
  color: #aaa;
  display: block;  For Firefox 
 }

</style>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Oops..just edited it, thanks.